# Create Observable with dispose handler rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

We want to observe the changes in the size of a view and we create an extension like this:

```
fun View.layoutSizeObservable(): io.reactivex.Observable<Size> {
    return io.reactivex.Observable.create<Size> { emitter ->
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            Log.d("MainFragment", "ViewTreeObserver Listener called back.")
            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                emitter.onNext(Size(measuredWidth, measuredHeight))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then we use it like this, which works fine functionally:

```
sizeChangedDisposable = titleTextView.layoutSizeObservable().subscribe { size: Size ->
    Log.d("MainFragment", "Size changed subscribe on $size")
}
```

However, one thing that is not exactly what we want is that the `Listener` is added via `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`, but never removed.

We can call `sizeChangedDisposable.dispose()` which will properly stop the subscription:

> D/MainFragment: Size changed subscribe on $size

But this will continue to get called:

> D/MainFragment: ViewTreeObserver Listener called back.

How and where do we remove the layout listener call back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the listener when the `Disposable` is disposed. To be able to do that, set a `Cancellable` action to the emitter removing the listener.

**Example**

```
fun View.layoutSizeObservable(): io.reactivex.Observable<Size> {
    return io.reactivex.Observable.create<Size> { emitter ->
        val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            Log.d("MainFragment", "ViewTreeObserver Listener called back.")
            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                emitter.onNext(Size(measuredWidth, measuredHeight))
            }
        }

        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)

        emitter.setCancellable {
            Log.d("MainFragment", "ViewTreeObserver Listener removed.")
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library already has an `Observable` for [global layout listener](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/2.2.0/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/ViewTreeObserverGlobalLayoutObservable.java)

Comment: Thanks! Just a follow-up question: in the class `ObservableEmitter`, there are both a `void setCancellable(@Nullable Cancellable c)` and a `void setDisposable(@Nullable Disposable d)`. Is there a reason when to use one, and when to use the other?

Comment: No difference, just easier, you could do as well `emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
        })`

Comment: I tried this and just notice that it doesn't work. The `Listener called back` line is still being executed. I think it is probably because the listener is defined as a lambda function and we are creating a different instance of `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` on the `add` and `remove` function. But if we change that line to `val listener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener { ... }`, then everything is good.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Done